# Data.frame with both characters and numerics in one column

Tags: r

I have a function I'm using in R that requires input to several parameters, once as a numeric (1) and as a character (NULL). The default is NULL.

I want to apply the function using all possible combinations of parameters, so I used expand.grid to try and create a dataframe which stores these. However, I am running into problems with creating an object that contains both numerics and characters in one column.

This is what I've tried:

`comb<-expand.grid(c("NULL",1),c("NULL",1),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, which returns:

```
comb
Var1 Var2
1 NULL NULL
2    1 NULL
3 NULL    1
4    1    1
```

with all entries characters:

```
class(comb[1,1])
[1] "character"
```

If I now try and insert a numeric into a specific spot, I still receive a character:

```
comb[2,1]<-as.numeric(1)
class(comb[2,1])
[1] "character"
```

I've also tried it using `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`, or using expand.grid(c(0,1),c(0,1)) and then switching out the `0` for `NULL` but always have the exact same problem: whenever I do this, I do not get a numeric `1`.

Manually creating an object using `cbind` and then inserting the `NULL` as a character also does not help. I'd be grateful for a pointer, or a work-around to running the function with all possible combinations of parameters.

Comment: You can't have a column that contains both character and numeric data. It'll all be coerced to character. Think of the columns as variables. You can't have a variable that's half-character and half-numeric, can you?

Comment: You probably would have more luck with something like `expand.grid(c(NA,1),c(NA,1))` and then interpret the NAs as "NULL" in your function (although I also doubt that your really mean `NULL`; that has a specific meaning in R, and you shouldn't use a character version of it as a variable).

Comment: While I was indeed not aware of this rule about data.frames, since it's not a problem for rows to contain more than one data type, I am still not farther along. Is there a way to store a character and a numeric in one column? I saw a suggestion using lists, but a list can also only contain one datatype per element, no? Regarding the function, I will change the code so it works with `NA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have been told, generally speaking columns of data frames need to be a single type. It's hard to solve your specific problem, because it is likely that the solution is not really "putting multiple types into a single column" but rather re-organizing your *other* unseen code to work within this restriction.

As I suggested, it probably will be better to use the built in `NA` value as `expand.grid(c(NA,1),c(NA,1))` and then modify your function to use `NA` as an input. Or, of course, you could just use some "special" numeric value, like -1, or -99 or something.

The related issue that I mentioned is that you really should avoid using the character string "NULL" to mean anything, since `NULL` is a special value in R, and confusion will ensue.

These sorts of strategies would all be preferable to mixing types, and using character strings of reserved words like NULL.

All that said, it technically *is* possible to get around this, but it is awkward, and not a good idea.

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
> d$y <- list("a",1,2,3,"b")
> d
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 1
3 3 2
4 4 3
5 5 b
> str(d)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ y:List of 5
  ..$ : chr "a"
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 2
  ..$ : num 3
  ..$ : chr "b"
```